# Is there a bijection $f: X \to X$ such that $f(a) \succ a$ for some $a \in X$ and $f(x) \succeq x$ for all $x \in X?$

Tags: order-theory

$X$ is a prewellordered set with respect to $\succeq$. The prewellordering is in general not antisymmetric relation in contrast to a well-order,  i.e.  $x  \succeq y$  and $y  \succeq x$ doesn't imply $x=y.$ The map $f$ doesn't descend to the well-order induced by the prewellordering. 
The question looks simple at least for the case when prewellordering  is a well-order but what are formal  arguments?

Comment: If $f$ order preserving?

Comment: @drhab. No, it's not order preserving.

Answer (score 3):

$X=\omega\sqcup\omega=\left\{ \left(n,0\right)\mid n=0,1,\dots\right\} \cup\left\{ \left(n,1\right)\mid n=0,1,\dots\right\} $
ordered by:

$\left(n,0\right)\leq\left(m,0\right)$ , $\left(n,0\right)\leq\left(m,1\right)$
and $\left(n,1\right)\leq\left(m,1\right)$ for all $n,m\in\omega$.

Then $f:X\rightarrow X$ prescribed by $\left(0,0\right)\mapsto\left(0,1\right)$,
$\left(n+1,0\right)\mapsto\left(n,0\right)$ and $\left(n,1\right)\mapsto\left(n+1,1\right)$ is a bijection.

This with $\left(0,0\right)<\left(0,1\right)=f\left(0,0\right)$
and $\left(n,m\right)\leq f\left(n,m\right)$ for all $n,m\in\omega$.

Comment: An easier way to describe the preorder would be: $(n,i)\leq(m,j)$ if and only if $i\leq j$.

Comment: Thanks!  You mean probably  $(n+1,0) \mapsto (n,0).$

Comment: Ah, yes of course. Repaired.